# How to change a file name inside a bash script?

Tags: bash, scripts

I am writing a bash script file `mybash.sh`, which runs few bash commands, 
This is one command that every time the file name should be changed based on

```
#!/bin/bash
ls ./home/images
./command -opt ./path/to/db ./home/images/filename.png
```

`ls` is giving the file name, for example image1-00.png. How to change the code that automatically replaces the `filename` with the name of image in the `./home/images` directory?

Comment: I think you're asking [How to set a variable to the output from a command](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4651437/4518341), though your question is not clear.

Comment: @dsstorefile there is one inside `./home/images` which every time another file is copied inside the folder, so the name of images is changing every time

Comment: @wjandrea Thanks your solution is also working

Comment: @dsstorefile Globs don't expand inside quotes, so use `./home/images/*.png` instead of `"./home/images/*.png"`

Comment: I would guard against the case where there is accidentally more than one image: `images=( ./home/images/*.png ); ./command -opt ./path/to/db "${images[0]}"` -- store the filenames in an array and extract the first element.